# Dataframe from all possible combinations of values of given categories

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have

```
{"A":[0,1], "B":[4,5], "C":[0,1], "D":[0,1]}
```

what I want it

```
A   B   C   D
0   4   0   0
0   4   0   1
0   4   1   0
0   4   1   1
1   4   0   1
```

...and so on. Basically all the combinations of values for each of the categories.
What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You are looking to generate a cartesian product stored in a dataframe from the values of each key of a dictionary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `x` is your dict:

```
>>> pandas.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(*x.values())), columns=x.keys())
    A  C  B  D
0   0  0  4  0
1   0  0  4  1
2   0  0  5  0
3   0  0  5  1
4   0  1  4  0
5   0  1  4  1
6   0  1  5  0
7   0  1  5  1
8   1  0  4  0
9   1  0  4  1
10  1  0  5  0
11  1  0  5  1
12  1  1  4  0
13  1  1  4  1
14  1  1  5  0
15  1  1  5  1
```

If you want the columns in a particular order you'll need to switch them afterwards (with, e.g., `df[["A", "B", "C", "D"]]`.

Comment: How to do this efficiently for large dictionary